# Python Selenium Screen Scrape

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to screen scrape a website (snippet below)

The website takes an input, navigates to a second page and takes more inputs and finally displays a table. I fail at this step:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='agencies']/option[@value='13156']").click()
```

The error I get is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: 'Unable to locate element:
```

Which is strange because I do see the element (Commented out Display id). Any help/pointers, please?

(I tried requests/RoboBrowser -- can't seem to get the post to work but failed there as well)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import selenium
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://www.ucrdatatool.gov/Search/Crime/Local/OneYearofData.cfm'
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='state']/option[@value='1']").click()
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='groups']/option[@value='8']").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Next']").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5) # seconds

# Display id tags
#elementsAll = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id]')
#for elements in elementsAll:
#    print("id: ", repr(elements))
#    print("idName: ",elements.get_attribute("id"))
#    driver.implicitly_wait(5) # seconds

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='groups']/option[@value='2']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='year']/option[@value=1986]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='agencies']/option[@value='13156']").click()
```

**Update** -- the `below` works on Selenium. I intended to choose all options in the list box and save the query results...Thanks for the pointer, Alecxe!

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('agencies'))
for options in select.options:
    select.select_by_visible_text(options.text)

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('groups'))
for options in select.options:
    select.select_by_visible_text(options.text)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='year']/option[@value=1985]").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Get Table']").click()
```

Comment: You shall use the name, not number.

Comment: Thanks Alecxe! Onwards now to BeautifulSoup to read table....

If anyone knows of a more elegant way to do the above (Using Requests or RoboBrowser), please do comment. Many thanks to all readers, again!

Comment: @user3720674 you don't need `BeautifulSoup`, I'm pretty sure `selenium` would handle the case. Consider creating a separate SO question with details if you need help with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `option` with `13156` value in `select` with `agencies` id. There are values from `102` to `522`, you can see them by printing:

```
[element.get_attribute('value') for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//select[@id="agencies"]/option')]
```

Also, instead of finding `option`s by `value`, use [`Select`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html?highlight=select#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) and get options by text:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('agencies'))
print select.options
select.select_by_visible_text('Selma Police Dept')
```